# Why is a compact linear operator also a bounded linear operator?

Tags: linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, compact-operators

I know that a linear operator is bounded iff continuous, with these definitions of "bounded" and "continuous":

- a linear operator T (on H Hilbert space) is bounded if ∃M>0: ||Tf||≤M||f|| for all f in H;
- a linear operator T is compact if T(B) has compact closure, with B unitary closed ball (or a linear operator T is compact if every bounded sequence {xn} has a subsequence {xnk} such that {T(xnk)} converges).

Comment: Compact closure implies bounded. $T(B)$ bounded implies $T$ bounded by linearity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a compact operator is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802862/show-that-a-compact-operator-is-bounded)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was very helpful